# Count the no of saturdays and sundays in date range - oracle

Tags: oracle

I have two parameters(*start_Date,end_Date*) from **table1**

I'm trying to count no of saturdays and sundays in a date range

```
star_Date=8/20/2014 13:52
end_Date=8/28/2014 13:52
```

And result should be like this

```
Start_Date        end_date          No_of_leaves 
8/20/2014 13:52   8/28/2014 13:52       2
```

**Update Section**

```
SELECT retouch_req_time,retouch_submit_time,(
        SELECT Count(*) FROM (SELECT To_char(start_date + ( LEVEL - 1 ), 'fmday') dt 
        FROM (WITH t AS (SELECT To_date (retouch_req_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') start_date, To_date (retouch_submit_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') end_date FROM TT)) 
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= end_date - start_date + 1) WHERE dt IN ('friday','saturday')) as worked_hours
FROM TT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the number of saturdays and sundays like this:

```
with t(d) as (
  select sysdate + level from dual connect by rownum < 10
)
select count(case when trim(to_char(d, 'DAY')) in ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY') then 1 end) cnt from t

CNT
---
  2
```

If you don't have a range of dates then:

```
with t(a, b) as (
  select sysdate a, sysdate + 10 b from dual connect by rownum < 10
), t2(d) as (
  select a + level - 1 from t connect by rownum <= b - a
)
select count(case when trim(to_char(d, 'DAY')) in ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY') then 1 end) cnt from t2

CNT
---
  2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using hierarchical queries

```
WITH t 
     AS (SELECT To_date ('8/20/2014 13:52', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') start_date, 
                To_date ('8/28/2014 13:52', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') end_date 
         FROM   dual) 
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   (SELECT To_char(start_date + ( LEVEL - 1 ), 'fmday') dt 
        FROM   t 
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= end_date - start_date + 1) 
WHERE  dt IN ( 'friday', 'saturday' );


RESULT
------
2
```

* The dates are listed by expanding the range.
* The TO_CHAR function is used to obtain the weekday
* Count everthing which is a friday or saturday

If you want to find the day wise count, then you can try

```
SELECT To_char(dat, 'DY'), 
       Count(*) 
FROM   (SELECT To_date ('8/20/2014 13:52', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') 
               + num dat 
        FROM   (SELECT LEVEL - 1 num 
                FROM   dual 
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= Abs(To_date ('8/20/2014 13:52', 
                                        'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') - 
                                                             To_date ( 
                                        '8/28/2014 13:52' 
                                                             , 
                                        'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')) - 1 
               )) 
WHERE  To_char(dat, 'DY') IN ( 'FRI', 'SAT' ) 
GROUP  BY To_char(dat, 'DY');


RESULTS

TO_CHAR(DAT,'DY')   COUNT(*)
-----------------   --------
FRI                   1
SAT                   1
```

Comment: @realsprituals i modified your 1st query and ran it .. its giving missing select error .. can you help .. i update my query in update section in my question

Comment: You canntot use Common table expressions like this.